# How to change a large JSON file as Buffer in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, node-streams

I am using Nnode.JS to get a file(.json) using `multer` library and then filter some parts of the file and save it somewhere else.
Since the file can be large some times, I am using stream to read it and also I am using another package called `streamifier` to read the buffer.
Here is my code:

```
import { Response } from 'express';
const streamifier = require('streamifier');

    
    function uploadFile(file) {
        const json = streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer)
        return json.pipe(process.stdout)
    }
```

Here is the file which is the same as response for now:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
      "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
      },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
          ]
        },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
        }
      },
    { "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [
           [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
             [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
           ]

       },
       "properties": {
         "prop0": "value0",
         "prop1": {"this": "that"}
         }
       }
    ]
  }
```

So what is the best way to get only `geometry` and `properties` from the JSON file while also reading it in stream?

Note: the full code with NestJS is here

```
@Post('upload')
    @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
    @ApiBody({
        description: 'Geojson File',
        type: FileUploadDto,
    })
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Res() res: Response) {
        const json = streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer)
        return json.pipe(res)
    }
```

Comment: Something like [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) might help.

Comment: @Amadan, I used that actually but getting errors: `return streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer)
            .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
            .pipe(res)`

Comment: Any reason why you omitted both the relevant part of your code and the error messages you got? Please make sure you have a [example]. If your question is about extracting a property from a JSON stream, then have an example that shows an attempt at extracting a property from a JSON stream; `uploadFile`, `@Post` etc are irrelevant.

Comment: I dont get any error, my question was about how to filter the json file and get only the needed parts.

Comment: "I used that actually but getting errors" and still "I dont get any error"?

Comment: I meant if I use `JSONStream`,  I get error.

Comment: What error do you get if you use `JSONStream`?